# How can I write recursive XSLT code

Tags: xml, xslt, recursion, tree

I have dynamic XML data and I use following xslt code to generate html. XML structure contains chapter, subchapter, checklist and summary nodes.

- `<chapter>` contains `<subchapter>` and `<checklist>`
- `<subchapter>` contanins `<subchapter>` and `<checklist>`
- `<checklist>` contains `<summary>`

My code works but, all the time subchapter's content added before checklist.  If chapter involves checklist,subchapter nodes (first checklist), subchapter content created first.

**How can I correct this or how can I rewrite the following code as recursive?**

```
  <xsl:template match="chapter">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="chapter"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="chapter">    
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h2>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
          </h2>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="subchapter"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="checklist"/>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>



  <xsl:template match="subchapter">

      <tr>
        <td>
          <h3>
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
              <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
          </h3>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="subchapter"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="checklist"/>

  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="checklist">    
      <tr>
        <td>
          <h4>
            <xsl:attribute name="name">
              <xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
            </xsl:attribute>

            <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>

          </h4>
        </td>
      </tr>

      <xsl:apply-templates select="summary"/>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="summary">    
      <tr>
        <td>
          <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        </td>
      </tr>    
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: If you replace `<xsl:apply-templates select="subchapter"/><xsl:apply-templates select="checklist"/>` with `<xsl:apply-templates/>` or `<xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>` then you process child nodes or child elements in document order and by the order of your two `apply-templates`.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing (without seeing the input and the expected output, I can only guess), that instead of:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="subchapter"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="checklist"/>
```

you want :

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="subchapter | checklist"/>
```

If `chapter` contains **only** `subchapter` and `checklist` you can shorten that to:

```
<xsl:apply-templates/>
```